# Select all pods running on a K8s node for Cilium Policy

Tags: kubernetes, cilium

I am trying to use [Cilium Egress Gateway Policy](https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.12/gettingstarted/egress-gateway/) in my K8s cluster. I want to apply policy on all pods scheduled on Node X. How can I do that?

Using the podSelector field, I can pick pods which `matchLabels`. Theer is also a special label `io.kubernetes.pod.namespace` to select pods in a namespace. But I don't know how to filter for the pod's scheduled node (spec.nodeName).

Another possible solution is that I write a daemon set, which will get all pods on the node, and then call api-server to add a label for nodeName. But I need guidance how to write such daemon set, or if it's even secure to have the api-server credentials on the node.

Comment: I guess you are looking for host policies: https://docs.cilium.io/en/latest/security/policy/language/#hostpolicies

Comment: Cilium host policies don't apply to traffic from and to pods (unless we were talking about host-network namespaced pods).

Comment: I don't know of a way to implement what is requested here, other than having some piece of code adding the label per nodes. if you're still looking for a good way to solve this, I would describe the need related to the egress gateway; there may be another way to achieve your end goal.